# Windows 2008R2 :: Taskkill in a scheduled task

Tags: taskkill

I'm using

TASKKILL /FI "IMAGENAME eq xyz.exe" /FI "STATUS eq UNKNOWN" /F

in a batch which is run as scheduled task.

When I run the batch manually, the filters work fine. When I run it from ScheduledTasks with RunNow, all processes of xyz.exe are killed.

Any ideas ?

Regards,

Thomas